# Collision detection (CGRectIntersectRect)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, collision-detection, collision

I have two images: first image size is 50x85 and second image size is 50x113. When I touch the screen image goes up and second image is shown and when I release the screen image goes down and first image is shown. Now the problem is when I'm touching the screen collision happens earlier than when I'm not touching the screen.

How could I make that in second image about 30px at bottom won't collide, but image will still be there?

---

Edit: Here is some of the code:

```
-(void)AstronautMove
{
    [self Collision];
    Astronaut.center = CGPointMake(Astronaut.center.x, Astronaut.center.y + Y);
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    Y = -10;
    x.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"y.png"];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    Y = 17;
    x.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"x.png"];
}

-(void)Collision
{
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(Astronaut.frame, Landingarea.frame)) {
        [self EndGame];
        AstronautFire.hidden = YES;
        RedBorder.hidden = NO;
        AstronautCrashed.hidden = NO;
    }

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(AstronautFire.frame, Landingarea.frame)) {
        [self EndGame];
        AstronautFire.hidden = YES;
        RedBorder.hidden = NO;
        AstronautCrashed.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

I'm just moving the frame up and down. At the bottom is landing area. When Astronaut and landing area frames touch, collision happens. But when I'm moving Astronaut up bigger image is shown (50x113) and when I'm moving Astronaut down smaller image is shown (50x85). When I'm near landing area and I press to go up bigger image shows and collision happens.

Comment: Do we infer from your code sample, where you're just changing `Astronaut.center`, that you're not doing any animation, just instantaneously changing the frame? If you are doing any animation, show us that code. You also ask about `CGRectIntersectRect`, but don't show us where you're calling that. Bottom line, there isn't enough here for us to help you diagnose what's going on, much less make any recommendations.

Comment: I'm just moving the frame up and down. At the bottom is landing area. When Astronaut and landing area frames touch, collision happens. But when I'm moving Astronaut up bigger image is shown (50x113) and when I'm moving Astronaut down smaller image is shown (50x85).  When I'm near landing area and I press to go up bigger image shows and collision happens.

Comment: AstronautFire is the bigger image.                                                 -(void)Collision {
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(Astronaut.frame, Landingarea.frame)) {
        [self EndGame];
        AstronautFire.hidden = YES;
        RedBorder.hidden = NO;
        AstronautCrashed.hidden = NO;
        
    }
    
        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(AstronautFire.frame, Landingarea.frame)) {
            [self EndGame];
            AstronautFire.hidden = YES;
            RedBorder.hidden = NO;
            AstronautCrashed.hidden = NO;
            
        }
}

Answer (score 1):

From the code samples, it really is hard to follow what you're trying to do. Notably, it's unclear how (or even if) you're animating the moving of the various views.

Whether you're animating or not, it's not clear from your code sample as to where `AstronautMove` is called. Did you mean to call that from `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded`? But on the basis of what's been shared thus far, I don't see you calling `AstronautMove` and therefore don't see how you could possibly detect collisions.

Personally, I would have thought that you'd want to animate the moving of the views (it will render a more realistic and engaging moving of the views). And then, while an animation is underway, keep checking for a collision. In terms of how to "keep checking", you can use either a `NSTimer` or, even better, us a `CADisplayLink` (a mechanism to call a method each and every time the screen updates).

For example, you could do something like:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *view1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *view2;

@property (nonatomic, strong) CADisplayLink *displayLink;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50)];
    view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [self.view addSubview:view1];
    self.view1 = view1;

    UIView *view2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 150, 50, 50)];
    view2.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    [self.view addSubview:view2];
    self.view2 = view2;
}

#pragma mark - Handle touches

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self startAnimationTo:CGPointMake(50, 250) collisionChecking:YES];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self startAnimationTo:CGPointMake(50, 50) collisionChecking:NO];
}

#pragma mark - Handle starting and stopping of animation

- (void)startAnimationTo:(CGPoint)point collisionChecking:(BOOL)collisionChecking
{
    if (collisionChecking)
        [self startDisplayLink];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:0.0 options:0 animations:^{
        CGRect frame = self.view1.frame;
        frame.origin = point;
        self.view1.frame = frame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        // in case we never have collision, let's make sure we stop the display link
        if (collisionChecking)
            [self stopDisplayLink];
    }];
}

- (void)stopAnimation
{
    CALayer *layer = self.view1.layer.presentationLayer;

    [self.view1.layer removeAllAnimations];
    self.view1.frame = layer.frame;
    [self stopDisplayLink];
}

#pragma mark - Handle the display link & check for collisions

- (void)startDisplayLink
{
    self.displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(checkForCollision:)];
    [self.displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}

- (void)stopDisplayLink
{
    [self.displayLink invalidate];
    self.displayLink = nil;
}

- (void)checkForCollision:(CADisplayLink *)displayLink
{
    // Note, when checking for collision while an animation is underway, the `frame` of the
    // view represents the final location of the view, not the current location. To get the
    // current location, one has to grab the `presentationLayer`. So, we're going to get the
    // `presentationLayer` of each of the views and use those to determine a collision.

    CALayer *layer1 = self.view1.layer.presentationLayer;
    CALayer *layer2 = self.view2.layer.presentationLayer;

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(layer1.frame, layer2.frame)) {
        [self stopAnimation];
    }
}

@end
```

Or, in iOS 7, you can use UIKit Dynamics to animate the movement of the views, identifying collisions programmatically using a `UICollisionBehavior` and assigning a `collisionDelegate`:

```
@interface ViewController () <UICollisionBehaviorDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *view1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *view2;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIDynamicAnimator *animator;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISnapBehavior *snap;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50)];
    view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [self.view addSubview:view1];
    self.view1 = view1;

    UIView *view2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 150, 50, 50)];
    view2.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    [self.view addSubview:view2];
    self.view2 = view2;

    self.animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.view];

    // create behavior that will detect collisions, calling the `UICollisionBehaviorDelegate`
    // methods if and when collisions are detected

    UICollisionBehavior *collision = [[UICollisionBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[view1, view2]];
    collision.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = YES;
    collision.collisionDelegate = self;
    [self.animator addBehavior:collision];

    // in this example, I'm going to fix `view2` where it is, so it doesn't move when 
    // `view1` collides with it

    UIAttachmentBehavior *attachment = [[UIAttachmentBehavior alloc] initWithItem:self.view2 attachedToAnchor:self.view2.center];
    [self.animator addBehavior:attachment];

    // finally, let's specify that neither view1 nor view2 should rotate when 
    // snapping, colliding, etc.

    UIDynamicItemBehavior *noRotate = [[UIDynamicItemBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[view1, view2]];
    noRotate.allowsRotation = NO;
    [self.animator addBehavior:noRotate];
}

- (void)addSnap:(CGPoint)point
{
    [self removeSnap];

    self.snap = [[UISnapBehavior alloc] initWithItem:self.view1 snapToPoint:point];
    [self.animator addBehavior:self.snap];
    [self.animator updateItemUsingCurrentState:self.view1];
}

- (void)removeSnap
{
    if (self.snap) {
        [self.animator removeBehavior:self.snap];
        self.snap = nil;
    }
}

#pragma mark - Handle touches

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self addSnap:CGPointMake(75, 225)];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self addSnap:CGPointMake(75, 75)];
}

#pragma mark - UICollisionBehaviorDelegate

// you can use these to be informed when there is a collision

- (void)collisionBehavior:(UICollisionBehavior *)behavior beganContactForItem:(id<UIDynamicItem>)item withBoundaryIdentifier:(id<NSCopying>)identifier atPoint:(CGPoint)p
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);

    [self removeSnap];
}

- (void)collisionBehavior:(UICollisionBehavior *)behavior beganContactForItem:(id<UIDynamicItem>)item1 withItem:(id<UIDynamicItem>)item2 atPoint:(CGPoint)p
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);

    [self removeSnap];
}
@end
```

Or, for a game, [SpriteKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html) might be even better. You can google "SpriteKit example" and you'll probably find plenty of good introductions to SpriteKit.

I know that neither of the above examples are quite what you're doing, but hopefully it illustrates a couple of techniques for identifying collisions, which you could adapt for your app.

Comment: 1. This is the code for moving, Y is int.    
                                                                                           2. Here is the code:

    -(void)Moving {

    [self Collision];

    Image.center = CGPointMake(Image.center.x, Image.center.y + Y);

    }

    -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event   {
    OTHER STUFF
    }
    Y = -7;
    }

    -(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    OTHER STUFF
    }
    Y = 7;
    }

Comment: @user2932903 1. Like all of the code snippets you've shared with us, this is insufficient to diagnose the problem. And where you have questions about the collisions not being detected when they should, the devil is going to be in those details. 2. Please stop posting code in comments; it's really hard to read. Edit your original question, updating the code samples there. 3. Just like the `AstronautMoved` method, you're not showing us where and how `Moving` is getting called. We can't diagnose why collisions are not detected if you don't show us where you call it.

Comment: Rob has provided a complete sample here along with comments, code and reasoning for it. Covering not just collision detection that is originally asked, but also one of the newer topics such as `UIKit Dynamics`. This is a very good answer that deserves appreciation. +1